# for loop find in list with if statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop

I have the following question:

considering the given list :

```
list = ['12','8','3']
```

why does `print('8' in list)` returns **True**

whereas

```
for i in range(5):
     if '8' in list == True:
         (code)
```

**doesn't execute my code** inside the if loop ?
Could someone explain me why, and how could I make this work ?

Maybe this question has already been asked but I don't see with which keywords I should search for it.
Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: `print('8' in list)` does not print True, it prints False, as expected. Are you sure you haven't redefined `list` somewhere? Also, note that `list` is already defined in Python as a function handle, and you've just lost the ability to call `list()` by defining `list` as `['12','5','3']`. **Change `list` to something else, like *`lists`*, that doesn't conflict with builtins**.

Comment: It's not a good idea to name your variables `list`, because that's a [built-in type constructor](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#list)

Comment: Also, your for-loop was unnecessary. `'8' in list` will walk through the list for you anyway.

Comment: rolled back to (almost) initial question, so that Matthew Cliatt answer which is good matches your initial problem. This is never good to edit your question because it makes the answers not looking like they answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You seem to have some logical errors in your code, so I'll try to outline what you should be doing.

- You shouldn't name variables `str` or `list` or `int` because they might conflict with Python's built in keywords.
- Your check did `if '8' in list`, but that will test if the ***string*** 8 is in the list, not the number. Drop the apostrophes.
- You don't have to put `if 8 in list` in a loop, it'll do the looping and testing for you.

---

### Solution

To check if a number is in a list, you can use python's built in `in` keyword, your write your own code to do the checking.

Remember not to use keywords like `list`, so I've changed the name to `myList` in these examples.

#### Using `in`

```
if 8 in myList:   # Note that you don't have to say == True
    print('8 is in the list!')
```

#### Or using `for i in myList)`

```
for i in myList:
    if i == 8:
        print('8 is in the list!')**
```

#### **Or** using `for i in range(len(myList))`

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i] == 8:
        print('8 is in the list!')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My code didn't work as I wanted due to my bad syntax. The problem was I wrote _== True_ after my If statement, which I shouldn't and made my code impossible to be ran